# Material UI Customized styled element with theme

Tags: material-ui

I'm starting to use Material UI in my project.
I have created a theme with some basic definitions, using my css variables:

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import theme from './_my-variables.scss';

const muiTheme = createTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: theme['color-blue'], // 'color-blue' is my css variable
        },
    },
    typography: {
        fontFamily: theme['brand-font'], // 'brand-font' is my css variable
    },
}
```

I also used ThemeProvider in my App layout:

```
export const App = (props) => {
       return (<Provider store={store}>
             <ThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>
                <ConnectedRouter history={historyRef.history}>
                   <Layout {...props} />
                </ConnectedRouter>
             </ThemeProvider>
      </Provider>);
};
```

I have a page with MUI elements, and it **works fine** and takes the new primary color and the new font.

```
<Box>
  <Paper>
    <Checkbox color="primary" />  <!-- I can see my new color in the page! Yay! -->
    some text
  </Paper>
</Box>
```

**Now** I want to create a **custom element** - like `<MyCustomizeBox>` that will have a different properties, **using my css variables** (for example - a specific width, defined in my variables).

How do I define them in my theme and how to use it to customize a new element?
I prefer not to user classes () because I want to create a generic elements for reusing.  Also I don't want to change **all** Boxes in my app - only the customized ones.

I tries to use "withStyles" but I was getting the default theme instead of my customized theme and I saw on Google that I'm not support to use both "withStyles" and theme together.

Answer (score 0):

At last, found the answer:

```
import { styled } from '@mui/system';

const MyCustomizedPaper = styled(Paper)(({ theme }) => ({
    width: theme.custom.myCustomWidthCssVar
}));

<MyCustomizedPaper ></MyCustomizedPaper >
```